# Jquery autocomplete selected values getting dissapeared sometimes

Tags: php, jquery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#cat_name1").autocomplete("auto_suggest.php", {
         minChars: 0,
         max: 120,
         autoFill: true,
         mustMatch: true,
         matchContains: false,
         selectFirst: true,
         scrollHeight: 220,
     });
});
</script>
<div id="categorrySelection" class="Post_catsearchcontent">
   <label>Search Category <span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></label>
   <input name = "cat_name1" type = "text" id="cat_name1" 
          id="cat_name1" class="required" size="35" >
   <input name = "cat1" type = "hidden" id="cat1">
</div>
```

In my case when I search something in textbox, it shows me the values but when I select the value then some times it works fine and sometimes the text box become empty after selection.

How can I debug this ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need a autocomplete="off" attribute in your input element.